# Confidence intervals for accuracy metrics: pros and cons of the bootstrap method compared to variance estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I want to report the CI for metrics like F1 and AUC.
I'm a bit confused on when it's better to bootstrap it, or when to use a formula.

For F1 there are several works that estimate the variance and derive a (symmetric) confidence interval, like:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8936911.

Similarly for AUC there is the Delong method, and others.

However for all these metrics, we could bootstrap them by sampling with replacement, computing the metric for every sample, and then taking the percentiles of the distribution, like the 2.5% 97.5% and percentiles.

Which of these approaches is expected to be better?

I guess an issue with the bootstrap method is that it's slow to compute it thousands of times. Is that the only reason there are works to create a closed formula for the CI ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's situations where you can bootstrap. If your sample size is large, then bootstrapping when possible is really convenient for a number of reasons:

1. If it works, then it works for almost any metric you can define, while frequentist analytical solutions tend to be derived for one metric at a time (bad luck if your metric of interest is not covered)
2. It's easy to implement (assuming a straightforward bootstrapping scheme is appropriate for the situation and the metric is easy to calculate for a sample).

Where bootstrapping has problems is

1. When sample size is small, then the discreteness of bootstrapping can make it inefficient.
2. When another simple solution is easily available/already implemented, why do it, when it often takes longer to run/is a little bit more complex to implement than running a well-validated package that someone else already wrote?
3. Sometimes you just cannot bootstrap in a valid way. E.g. multiple-rate-multiple-case (MRMC) studies tend to make it very hard to bootstrap (some solutions still have a bootstrap component, but it's nightmarishly complicated*), because everything is in a way correlated with everything (you have both the same raters looking at cases, as well as the same cases being looked).

As the other answer mentioned, one approach is a form of mixed effects model that describes the whole process. We took that approach for a MRMC study, where there were 3 possible diagnoses, recently. The Methods Section of the [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaip.2023.01.017) outlines the approach:

> We analyzed the primary outcome using a Bayesian model that jointly
> modeled each patient’s true disease status (ie, expert panel
> diagnosis) as a categorical random variable and the diagnoses given
> for each patient by each physician or algorithm (determined using
> multinomial logistic regression). The multinomial logistic regression
> model included a separate intercept term for each combination of
> disease (asthma, COPD, and ACO) and group (PCPs, pulmonologists, and
> the AC/DC tool), as well as a random case and random rater effect.

We took this approach, because we could not find any published methods that applied to the metrics our clinical colleagues wanted to look at (most MRMC literature is about AuROC and as mentioned, simple bootstrapping does not work). We ended up fitting this in a Bayesian way using Stan, because that deals with the uncertainties sensibly. It might be possible to fit such a model with something like PROC NLMIXED in SAS and to get confidence intervals that way (they have a decent automatic procedure for SEs there that uses the delta method) in a large study, but the Bayesian approach deals more naturally with (nearly) empty cells.

* Regarding "nightmarishly complicated", look at the complexity in these papers for getting AuROC estimates with CIs from MRMC studies:

- Brandon D. Gallas, Gene A. Pennello, and Kyle J. Myers. Multireader
  multicase variance analysis for binary data. J. Opt. Soc. Am. A, 24(12):
  B70–B80, Dec 2007. doi: [10.1364/JOSAA.24.000B70](https://dx.doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.24.000B70).
- Brandon D. Gallas, Andriy Bandos, Frank W. Samuelson, and Robert F.
  Wagner. A framework for random-effects roc analysis: Biases with the boot-
  strap and other variance estimators. Communications in Statistics - Theory
  and Methods, 38(15):2586–2603, 2009. doi: [10.1080/03610920802610084](https://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03610920802610084).

Comment: Nice answer :-) I'll have to read the papers, but I think the MRMC scenario is part of what I refer to has situations with crossed random factors at top level - which requires independence on both (all top-level) random factors. If that suspicion is correct, at least for my data I anywanys better set up the nightmarishly complicated resampling since I need the same independent splitting already during hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. How can we determine if the sample size is large enough to bootstrap? For example if I want to compute the CI for F1 for 100 scores, is it large enough? how about 1000?

Comment: Wrt small sample size situations, I take the following approach: for very small n one may as well do an exhaustive calculation of all possibilities for "ordered drawing with replacement". For somewhat larger n, a usual random bootstrapping. Sure, the results are then discrete, but that's because the underlying binomial distribution is inherently discrete (and that's what causes a substantial part of the high variance problems with these figures of merit). So a bit of care is needed to actually get at least the desired coverage. However, in practice for what I've seen so far the inefficiency is

Comment: ... of small consequence: while the coverage properties are not nice, that typically doesn't matter since they still very clearly give the practically relevant message of "too uncertain to allow any meaningful conclusions". (And the same happens also for formula-based calcuation: e.g. for binomial proportions, a variety of different approximations for the c.i. are available, and they can differ for small n. But in practice, it won't matter if the confidence interval is 60 - 100 % or 65 - 100 %: both is typically not acceptable for application use)

Comment: With too few observations, permutation tests (and similarly bootstrapping) are inefficient. Few observations would be in terms of the number in each cell. For larger numbers per cell (traditionally people have had rules of thumb of >5 for the minimum amount in any cell), asymptotic frequentist methods should be okayish (but there's a considerable area where bootstrapping/exact permuation methods are possible, in which case why not use them?). However, Bayesian methods tend to perform pretty well for all settings (until you need to do MCMC with 10,000 or 100,000s of observations...).

Answer (score 5):

I tend to have data with inherent structure, such as multiple samples per patient, multiple measurements per sample and the like.
In that situation, the statistically independent unit is typically the patient rather than the row of the data matrix. (In some cases, independence is even more complicated, with multiple top-level sources of variance.)

While I can easily bootstrap patients (or more general: set up a resampling procedure so that statistical independence is obeyed*) the analytical c.i. calculations I've met so far assume statistical independence at the row level. I.e., they do not accomodate more complex real-life data structure.

It's not that I would speak against using analytical formulations of variance (though I'd recommend to closely check the "small print" of the respective method) - I just don't meet nice data that would allow me to use them...

However, if your data meets the requirements of the analytical/parametric calculation, I'd expect it to have more power than bootstrapping.

What I do use is e.g. binomial c.i.s for proportions like sensitivity, specificity or the predictive values with patient number as sample size. Often, I can show that model instability is negligible compared to this, and I thus get a sensible approximation. (And the result is often anyways so wide that it does a good job serving as warning not to overinterprete the results...)

Sometimes I use this also as back-of-the-envelope calculation before experiments start: the c.i. won't get any better than that - if that is not satisfactory, more patients are needed right from the beginning.

---

Mixed models that describe the underlying structure for the prediction error may be a way here, but I haven't seen any papers applying this so far. It is, however, an approach that I'm looking into.

I have a sneaking suspicion that situations where the variance on the error estimate can sensibly be approximated as stemming from a single source are actually very rare (and my educated guess is that this is where patient-to-patient variance dominates everything and if that's the case with the final error estimate, it is rarely of practical use).
Of course, one may still sum the contributions of various sources of error into one total variance - but also there, analytical calculation would need to account for the data structure and the corresponding sources of variance.

---

*Since I typically also work with high-dimensional data, I anyways have to set up such splitting procedures to generate suitable test data to produce the generalization error estimates: the fanciest variance estimator is of no use if my validation procedure has a (large) optimistic bias. Also keep in mind that optimistically biased test results on classification tasks often lead to  optimistically biased (too narrow) variance estimates as well.

---

**Update: back of the envelope calculations**

Since I don't use F1, I'll outline mostly what I do for sensitivity (or analogously specificity). Sensitivity is the (observed) fraction of correctly predicted tested cases of the positive class, and we can thus use binomial confidence intervals. The width of these depends on the denominator, i.e. the number of tested cases of the positive class, and on the true value of the sensitivity (with maximum width for 50 % sens and minimum width for 0 and 100 % sens).

For the minimum confidence interval width, we can use the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics)): assuming we's observe no errors, the 95 % c.i. for sensitivity would be roughy ranging from 1 to $1 - \frac{3}{n}$

However, we can also calculate minimum and maximum c.i. width depending on the number of tested positive cases before any experimental results are available:

[image: minimum and maximum confidence interval width for sensitivity as function of tested cases]

... and compare that to the the requirements of the application.
(One can also set up calculation to estimate reasonable sample sizes based on expected performance and application requirements. One scenario I've been using is specifying for an application situation "super nice", "OK" and "not really acceptable" performance. If for the discussed sample size "super nice" performance couldn't be reliably distinguished from "not really acceptable", sample size is insufficient)

To get guesstimates for other measures that are not simply an observed fraction of a pre-specified number of test cases (such as F1), you could either start with the variance of the binomially distributed simple fractions and do error propagation, or set up simulations (which would be quite similar to bootstrapping).

Comment: Nice answer and agree with almost everything. Added my own perspective as another answer (mostly adding something regarding situations where you just can't bootstrap easily). Regarding your comment on "mixed models that describe the underlying structure for the prediction error", we have done something like that [recently](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jaip.2023.01.017) as I mention in my answer.

Comment: @Björn: thank you for the literature links :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer ! How would you do back of the envelope calculations about the CI for F1 for example. Would you assume some distribution of the scores for that?

Comment: Depends if each case is an independent assessment (i.e. each case assessed once with no repeated assessments). If so, you can use a Dirichlet(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5) prior (0.5 on diagonal, 0.25 off-diagonal) for being in each cell of the confusion matrix, get the posterior (add observed count in each cell), you then draw random variables (=random confusion matrices) from this distribution & calculate the F1-score on them. CI := the 2.5th to 97.5th percentile of these score. Is that easier than boostrapping? Not sure, but should be okay if some cells are near zero.

Comment: @Björn: we don't even need the assumption of each observation being an independent case. We "only" need the random drawing to account for the repeated assessments: F1 calculation does not need integer numbers in the confusion matrix, so we can weight observations so that each independent experimental unit gets a total weight of 1 (possibly distributed across cells). We'd also need assumptions/estimates of variance and distribution for the different sources of variance (e.g. separate within subject, between subject). In the end, the structure is probably rather similar to the bootstrapping.

Comment: If you figure out how to do that for a MRMC study where there's, say, 100 cases, 200 raters and each rater only diagnoses 20 randomly chosen cases then I'll be impressed. Even worse, assume there's two different groups of raters (that e.g. had different training) and you want the difference in F1-score. If you bootstrap cases, you don't account for the variation coming from rater, if you bootstrap raters you don't account for variation from cases. Perhaps bootstrapping cases and raters somehow works? But never seen that described. I'd really like to see a simulation study to show that works...

Comment: @Björn: I'll start with the somewhat easier but closely related problem of setting up adequate splitting for cross validation. "bootstrap raters -> don't account for variation from cases": even worse, where like here generalization error is concerned: the data leak in cases causes optimistic bias (and that optimistic bias for figures of merit like accuracy, sensitivity, F1 is linked to underestimating variance), so that doesn't work at all.